# Animations inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a view from time to time inside an item of a `ListView`. It is a custom view, it extends `RelativeLayout`, and its purpose is to get some information from time to time from several sources (including internet), and to display it.
Whenever new information is available, a new child view is created programatically. The old view is animated out of the custom view (RelativeLayout), while the new view is animated in, exactly as a ViewFlipper works.
This view works fine when placed in regular layouts, but I have issues when placing it into a ListView's item. The issue is that it stops redrawing itself after one or two scrolls on the list - right after it gets out of the screen and comes back again. The animations are not visible anymore and the custom view only gets drawn when interacting with the list.
I tried invalidating the view, invalidating the list and other options, however, this does not work...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is some code resembling the exact mechanism I tried for my custom view (here I used a ViewFlipper to check if something is wrong with my view. Apparently it behaves the same, the flipper is not redrawn after interacting with the list)

```
package com.test.viewflipper;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class ViewFlipperTestActivity extends ListActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

  private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
  private Animation TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_IN = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
  private Animation TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_OUT = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewFlipper.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(params));
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_IN);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_OUT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
      button.setText("Button " + i);
      viewFlipper.addView(button);
    }
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    setListAdapter(new AdListAdapter(layoutInflater));
  }

  private class AdListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public AdListAdapter(LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
      this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      /* return the ad container for the first position */
      if (position == 0) {
        return viewFlipper;
      }
      else {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText("Item " + position);
        return view;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom view have you tried to start the animation manually? Creating the animation programmatically or by xml and then using `view.startAnimation(animation)`.

Also could you show some code?

---

**Update:**

Ok, first of all, the animation starts every second. But I would recommend removing the `viewFlipper` from the activity and rewriting the custom adapter to this:

```
private class AdListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public AdListAdapter(Context context) {
  super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
  // NOTE: This should be done with an xml
  viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(context);
  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  viewFlipper.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(params));
  viewFlipper.setInAnimation(TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_IN);
  viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(TRANSLATE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_VIEW_OUT);
  viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button.setText("Button " + i);
    viewFlipper.addView(button);
    // add an item to the adapter
    add("Item " + i);
  }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (position == 0) {
    // check if it's flipping
    if(!viewFlipper.isFlipping()) {
      viewFlipper.startFlipping();
    }
    return viewFlipper;
  } else if(convertView == viewFlipper) {
    // makes sure that the flipping is stopped when the viewFlipper is reused
    if(viewFlipper.isFlipping()) {
      viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
    }
    convertView = null;
  }
  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
 }
}
```

and then create it using:

```
setListAdapter(new AdListAdapter(this));
```

I haven't tested it, but it may work this way apart from simplifying the code and reuse of views (small important quirks of Android)

Comment: Well the animation is started manually every 10 seconds. The problem is that the view is not redrawn, after getting out of the list visible items and coming back again. I put logs in my app, and the animation process is triggered. However, on the UI is not updated (not redrawn).

Comment: I've updated the answer with a possible solution. Although untested for the moment, let me know if it works ;)